# How to add a string to an integer in Python?

Tags: python, string, integer, typeerror

I was writing this code when I encountered an error:

```py
name = 'mahbod'
age = 13
print(age + name)
```

The error I receive is:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

I expected that since the str is multiplied by the int, it will be added together

Comment: try print(str(age) + name)

Comment: print(age , name)

Comment: `since the str is multiplied by the int` what do you mean? the string is added to the int, which python doesn't accept. to be able to *concatenate* the two, into `"13mahbod"`, you would need to convert `age` to a string: `str(age)`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways. Personally, I prefer f-strings.

You can use any of the following:

1. `print(f"{age}{name}")`
   or better `print(f"Name={name}, age={age}")`
2. convert int to string:
   `print(str(age)+name)`
3. use comma:
   `print(age,name)`

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way to do it :)

```
name = 'mahbod '
age = 13
result = name + str(age)
print(result)  # Output: 'mahbod 13'
```